# save config.txt data in doubly linked list

Tags: c

I'm currently trying to create a console based solitaire game in c. I want a txt file to "simulate the deck" meaning that the config file should have all cards from BLACK A,2,3,4.... to RED J,Q,K....

I succesfully read and tokenized my config file but I'm clueless on how to save the "cards" in a doubly linked list.

Heres the code I've written so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


typedef struct card
{
  char color;
  int value;
  char name[2];
  struct card * prev;
  struct card * next;
} CARD_TYPE;


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  for (int i = 0; i < argc; i++)
  {
    printf("argv[%d] = %s\n", i, argv[i]);
  }

  int counter_red = 0;
  int counter_black = 0;

  char buffer[255];


  FILE* path = fopen (argv[1],"r");

  if (path == NULL)
  {
    printf("[ERR] Invalid file!\n");
    return 3;
  }

  while(fgets(buffer, 255, path) != NULL )
  {
    if (strlen(buffer) == 1) //string is empty
    {
      continue;
    }
    CARD_TYPE* temp = malloc(sizeof(CARD_TYPE));//DONT FORGET TO FREE
    temp->color = '\0';
    temp->name[0] = '\0';

    char *read = strtok(buffer," ");
    while (read != NULL)
    {
      if (strcmp (read, "BLACK" ) == 0 )
      {
        counter_black ++;
      }
      else if (strcmp (read, "RED" ) == 0 )
      {
        counter_red ++;
      }
        printf("%s", read);
        read = strtok(0, " ");

    }

  }

  if (counter_black != 13)
  {
    printf("[ERR] Invalid file!\n");
  }
```

So now I want to save the cards in the correct order(the same exact order as in the file).

Is this possible to do all of this in one loop?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I have seen this question recently. Are you in a class which has this as homework assignment?

Comment: When you type in `"RED"`, do you use 3 or 4 keystrokes?  (I suspect 4).  Suggest changing `strtok(...," ");` --> `strtok(...," \n");`  ( 2 places).

Comment: Tip: Use surrounding printable text to better see leading and trailing whitespace: `printf("%s", read);` --> `printf("<%s>\n", read);`

Answer (score 0):

You have a `CARD_TYPE* temp` you need to (name better and) populate. You're walking through your buffer, and you check if the card in the buffer is black. So you'd set the values of your card.So:

```
while (read != NULL)
{
  if (strcmp (read, "BLACK" ) == 0 )
  {
    temp->color = // what goes here?
    counter_black ++;
```

And then you need to find out what card rank it is. You need more information from the file. How do you do that?    (And what if the information doesn't make sense? How does this thing fail?). For now the prev and next pointers are just NULL.

Then you need to add this temporary card to a doubly linked list.   You should probably have a list declared somewhere. Let's call it

```
CARD_TYPE* deck;
```

The deck can simply be set to the first card once you make it. But it's a list. So the second card you read from the file would be set to.... what? Where does the card go?     (You're going to want to make a separate function for adding cards to a list. Something that mallocs some space and updates a list and leaves it in a valid state.)

And your teacher reminded you to free all your memory when you're done with it. It's good practice to walk through the list and free it all one by one before exiting the program. That way you can pick this code up and use it elsewhere, where it won't live at the top of main.c